# is there is any way to include files?

Tags: rules

I am writing PHP code in a rule, where I include another PHP file.

```
include_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';
```

Where do I need to include files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the standard PHP way:

1. `require 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';`
2. `include_once  'includes/google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';`
3. `include ('includes/google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php');`

or Drupal way:

```
include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';
```

Comment: `module_load_include();` function - [Drupal API documentation][1] - to include any PHP files from within your or other modules where needed,

 [1]: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_load_include/7

Comment: seems this is not working for me. even i didnt any kind of error

Comment: Also where i need to place google-api-php-client folder?

Comment: Wherever you want to @AnkitaKashyap; a custom module or in the libraries folder might make most sense, but it depends what you're doing

Comment: @Clive: i am new to drupal. i place external directory in sites/all/libraries folder ..  and in rules i am not getting any error

Comment: You shouldn't necessarily expect to see an error, `include` and `include_once` are designed to fail with a warning

Comment: `include_once` is a PHP way more then a Drupal way even you used `DRUPAL_ROOT`....

Answer (score 3):

1. You can use [`module_load_include()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_load_include/7.x) to include a PHP file.

   ```
   module_load_include('php', $type, 'includes/google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload');
   ```

   Where type can be either theme name or module name. I guess in this you are building some drupal module so it must be module type. In which case it will look for autoload.php file inside your name module directory. However internally it will do the require_once instead of include_once :)
2. You can use [Libraries API](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) module to include a php file. For this you will have to keep this google-api-php-client inside libraries folder. And you will perform these steps to implement it.

   ```
   function hook_libraries_info() {
     $path = libraries_get_path('google-api-php-client');
     set_include_path($path."/src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR .  get_include_path());
     $libraries['google-api-php-client'] = array(
     'name' => 'Google OAuth2 Library',
     'vendor url' => 'http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client',
     'download url' => 'http://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/archive/master.zip',
     'version arguments' => array(
       'file' => 'src/Google/Client.php',
       'pattern' => '/LIBVER = "([0-9\.a-z]+)/',
       'lines' => 40,
     ),
     'versions' => array(
       '1.0.5-beta' => array(
         'files' => array(
           'php' => array(
             'src/Google/Client.php',
           )
         ),
       ),
       '1.1.5' => array(
         'files' => array(
           'php' => array(
             'src/Google/autoload.php',
           )
         )
       )
     ),
     'files' => array(
       'php' => array(
         'src/Google/Client.php',
       ),
      ),
     );
     return $libraries;
   }
   ```

   Note: The version is 1.0.5-beta, so you may need to change the version as per your API version.

   Then to include this library in another module.

   ```
   function hook_init() {
     $path = libraries_get_path('google-api-php-client');
     if ($path) {
       set_include_path($path."/src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
     }
   }
   ```
3. Since it comes it composer.json/autoload.php you can use these modules to load it automatically from libraries folder.
   [X Autoload](https://www.drupal.org/project/xautoload), [Composer Autoload](https://www.drupal.org/project/composer_autoload), [Composer Vender Autoload](https://www.drupal.org/project/composer_autoloader), although you will still need to define the location inside your module.

   #### Using the XAutoload module

   ```
      function mymodule_libraries_info() {
        return array(
          'google-api-php-client' => array(
            'name' => 'Google Client Library',
            'xautoload' => function($adapter) {
              /** @var \Drupal\xautoload\Adapter\LocalDirectoryAdapter $adapter */
              // Scan sites/all/libraries/google-api-php-client/composer.json to look for
              // autoload information.
              $adapter->composerJson('composer.json');
            }
          )
        );
      }
   ```

Comment: where i need to place google-api-php-client folder?

Comment: For 2 and 3. place it inside sites/all/libraries folder.

Comment: Can't be do in simple way?

Comment: Well the most simple way is to place it inside a module. Say **gapi** and place the google-api-php-client inside it somewhere say includes within gapi module. Now you can get the autoload.php function from any other module or php or inc or from gapi.module itself file by just saying `module_load_include('php', 'gapi', '/includes/google-api-php-client');` at the top of file or inside functions where you want to get those functions.

Comment: i  am not getting any error.under debug mode  i am able to see the condition php_eval evaluated to FALSE

Comment: What you are doing is cryptic for me and cannot be answered without having a glimpse at what you are doing. Well it end up being another question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40935/discussion-between-ankita-kashyap-and-sarathkm).